# defining recurrence functions in java

Tags: java, c, recurrence

I have the following recurrence functions:

```
A(T)=4/3A(T-1)-4/7C(T-1), for T>0 and A(0)=3
B(T)=5/7B(T-1)-8/5A(T-1), for T>0 and B(0)=5
C(T)=7/2C(T-1)-3/7B(T-1), for T>0 and C(0)=10
```

I would like to define these functions in Java, I wrote the following code:

```
        int A(int t)
        {
            int A0 = 3;
            if(t>0){
            A0 = ((4/3)*A(t-1))-((4/7)*C(t-1));
            return A0;
            }
            return A0;
    }

int B(int t)
        {
            int B0 = 5;
            if(t>0){
            B0 = ((5/7)*B(t-1))-((8/5)*A(t-1));
            return B0;
            }
            return B0;
    }

int C(int t)
        {
            int C0 = 10;
            if(t>0){
            C0 = ((7/2)*C(t-1))-((3/7)*B(t-1));
            return C0;
            }
            return C0;
    }
```

these functions does not seem to give the correct values when they iterate for a random value of t
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why the C tag if the code is Java?

Comment: "these functions does not seem to give the correct values when they iterate for a random value of t" It would be better if you gave us **one value of `t`** that results in an incorrect answer

Comment: @kaylum this code snippet runs perfectly in C too

Comment: @4386427 for a example if you run them from t=0 to t=10 you only get the correct values for t=0

Comment: @aniani2020 I can explain you why it's not working in C but I'm not sure it's the same answer for java

Comment: that would be nice to know why aren't they working in C

Comment: @aniani2020 Your question is confusing. Why are you showing incorrect C code and also asking about writing it in java? So which is it? A java question or a C question.

Comment: If you could tell me why it is not working in C, I will try and write it in C and see if that solves the problem and then maybe it would be the same answer for Java

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for C as OP requested a C answer in a comment. (I think it's the same for java but I'm not sure):

Your formula obviously requires floating point calculations. But you are doing it all using `int`. Therefore you get strange results.

Example:

(4/3) will give the result 1

(5/7) will give the result 0

So change `int` to `double` and write (5.0/7.0) instead of (5/7)

Example:

```
double A(int t)
{
    double A0 = 3.0;
    if(t>0){
    A0 = ((4.0/3.0)*A(t-1))-((4.0/7.0)*C(t-1));
    return A0;
    }
    return A0;
}
```

or a bit shorter:

```
double A(int t)
{
    if (t == 0) return 3.0;

    return (4.0/3.0)*A(t-1) - (4.0/7.0)*C(t-1);
}
```

So a complete example

```
#include <stdio.h>

double B(int t);
double C(int t);

double A(int t)
{
    if (t == 0) return 3.0;
    return (4.0/3.0)*A(t-1) - (4.0/7.0)*C(t-1);
}

double B(int t)
{
    if (t == 0) return 5.0;
    return (5.0/7.0)*B(t-1) - (8.0/5.0)*A(t-1);
}

double C(int t)
{
    if (t == 0) return 10.0;
    return (7.0/2.0)*C(t-1) - (3.0/7.0)*B(t-1);
}

int main (void){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++ i) printf("%f %f %f\n ", A(i), B(i), C(i));    
    return 0;   
}
```

Output:

```
3.000000 5.000000 10.000000
 -1.714286 -1.228571 32.857143
 -21.061224 1.865306 115.526531
 -94.096793 35.030321 403.543440
 -356.058642 175.576526 1397.389046
 -1273.252883 695.105632 4815.614579
 -4449.450270 2533.708635 16556.748613
 -15393.599567 8928.912314 56862.745016
 -53017.796574 31007.553817 195192.930849
 -182229.213060 106976.727246 669886.306334
```

Comment: So I just tried this in C using double, I still get strange results and the other thing that I'm noticing that when iterating from i=0 to i<20 for example, using printf(A(i),B(i),C(i)), only the value of A is changing and B and C are stuck to the initial value all along the iteration, so I think something is wrong with the loops themselves

Comment: @aniani2020 What result do you get from t=1 ?

Comment: @aniani2020 `printf(A(i),B(i),C(i))` is not correct

Comment: @aniani2020 `t = 1` : `-1.714286 -1.228571 32.857143` which seems fine to me

Comment: I tried it right now, the value of A changes but I always get the same value of B and C, which I can't figure out why

Comment: @aniani2020 Check this https://ideone.com/LIvIAO